# If you generate a database using EF, do you also use EF to manage the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-generation, ef-model-first

*"Manage"* as in, make changes to the tables.

If yes, how does this work with multiple developers and multiple copies of the database (for development/production)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd generally say no as EF doesn't dynamically rebuild entities.

Comment: It does if you install the Database Generation Power Pack.

Comment: @Craig : So splitting hairs (and *how* I'm splitting them), EF doesn't but the Database Generation Power Pack does ;) LOL